Copy certain cells from one sheet to the next based on criteria, then delete source
I have 2 sheets - "Current" and "Archive" on the same workbook.
My intention is to

with a click of a button, shift certain cells from "Current" to the next available row in "Archive" based on "Done" column found on "Current". (ensuring date format stays the same)
delete the empty spaces from "Current" so that there won't be empty spaces.
Refresh the page because there is a power query on the same page which fetches data based on the "ISIN" column information found on "Current"

Before moving the data 
Current sheet (before i do anything on it)
With a click of a button, I wish to move highlighted cells (Column A-E) from "Current" to "Archive" when Column D (Action) = "Done"
Current sheet (Before)
Archive sheet (before i do anything on it) 
The cells from the previous step should be pasted in the next available row in Archive sheet. 
Archive sheet (Before)
After moving the data 
Current sheet (After clicking button) 
Ideally, the yellow highlighted cells should be deleted. Then the table (on the right, in green) should refresh to fetch the latest data from web (i have a power query running on that) 
Interim 
To refresh table 
Current sheet (end state) 
Archive sheet (After clicking button) 
Sometimes, after i run my query, the date format is not showing as expected. 
Archive sheet (After)
Can you help me to optimise my VBA to achieve my objective?

Sub Test()
    Dim ws          As Worksheet
    Dim e           As Variant
    Dim lr          As Long
    Dim r           As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Current")
    
    With Sheets("Archive")
        For r = 1 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            If ws.Cells(r, 4) = "Done" Then
                lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                For Each e In Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
                    .Range(e & lr) = ws.Range(e & r)
                    ws.Range(e & r).ClearContents
                Next e
            End If
        Next r
    End With
End Sub



Start things off by using the macro recorder to record the actions, then press ALT + F11 to view and copy the code. Post the code in your original question.

Amended my original question as requested!

This question is similar to: How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I tried inputting more details into my question. I supposed the link you provided doesn't have the information to dynamically delete a range of cells using a criteria.
